# more than on window.matchMedia does not work if not resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive, window-resize

I have code for responsive javascript, I use `$(window).resize(function()`, with `window.matchMedia` functions if the width is less than 768px it will perform functions and if more than 768px will use other functions.

the code works, but if my page is loaded the **"more than"** function doesn't work, but if I try to resize or use the "inspect element" the code works.

other cases, I use
$ (document) .ready (function () {
The function runs normally, but when trying to resize the screen size, the **"more than"** code does not work.

this is my code

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 765px)').matches) {
    //applied when the viewing area's width is 765px
    }else{
    //the function here does not work if the browser is not resized
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is to be expected, you are listening for the `resize` event, which at page load won't fire because the window hasn't been resized.

But you really don't need and even shouldn't listen for the resize event here.

The [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) instance returned by `matchMedia` has an `onchange` event handler. Listen only to this and don't create tons of useless MediaQueries:

Though this event will not fire at page load either, so you'd still have to call yourself the handler once.

```js
const query = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 765px)');
query.onchange = (evt) => {
  if( query.matches ) { console.log( "now it matches" ); } 
  else { console.log( "now it doesn't match" ); } 
};
// perform the initial check
query.onchange();
```